# How to setup Docker Overlay networks with hosts in different public networks or regions?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, overlay, docker-swarm, aws-networking

I have basic understanding of VXLAN and overlay networks in general. Docker overlay uses VXLAN under the hood to enable multi-host containers to talk among themselves.

However, what if these multi host containers are located in different public networks e.g. EC2 instances across different AWS regions and hence different public IP address networks. An EC2 instance will have private addresses within its own NAT AWS public address and so how will the docker daemon in the other EC2 contact it.
Is this even possible?(of course not recommended)

Maybe AWS has some workarounds but is Docker overlay networking solution across different public networks possible in general? If yes, how do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your nodes are on different VPCs in different regions, you could have them reach each other using [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html)